# Beginner Scheme list print

Tags: list, printing, scheme, racket

I am using DrRacket to learn Scheme, The language subset is racket (#lang racket). I have the following list/expression:

`(cons (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd)) (cons (cons 'e 'f) (cons 'g 'h)))`

When I press enter I get the following value printed out:

```
'(((a . b) c . d) (e . f) g . h)
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
'((( a . b) (c . d)) ((e . f) ( g . h)))
```

Can anyone explain what rules scheme uses to decide to print the value the way it does?

Attached is also a screen of the terminal:

[image]

Comment: use `list` instead of cons, `(list (list (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd)) (list (cons 'e 'f) (cons 'g 'h)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your expression is:

```
'((( a . b) . (c . d)) . ((e . f) . ( g . h)))
```

and not

```
'((( a . b) (c . d)) ((e . f) ( g . h)))
```

as you are expecting.

However it is not printed in that way, for the rules of printing of lisp languages. See for instance [this page](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/lisp-hints.txt) (it is for Common Lisp, but the printing rules are the same for Scheme):

> Notice that LISP prints linked lists a special way: it omits some of
>   the periods and parentheses. The rule is: if the cdr of a cons is nil,
>   LISP doesn't bother to print the period or the nil; and if the cdr of
>   cons A is cons B, then LISP doesn't bother to print the period for cons
>   A or the parentheses for cons B. So:
>
> (cons 4 nil)
>
> (4)
>
> (cons 4 (cons 5 6))
>
> (4 5 . 6)
>
> (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 nil)))
>
> (4 5 6)

Answer (score 3):

`cons` creates a pair, which is also a list. So, when you later `cons` something else to a list, you extend this list.

```
(cons 'a 'b)
==> (a . b)

(cons 'c '(a . b))
==> (c a . b)

(cons 'd '(c a . b))
==> (d c a . b)
```

And this is what happens when you `cons` new pair to another pair/list:

```
(cons 'something '(c . d))
==> (something c . d)

(cons '(a . b) (c . d))
==> ((a . b) c . d)
```

Sometimes it's helpful to draw pairs as boxes to see what is going on:

```
(cons 'a 'b)        (cons 'c 'd)
+---+---+          +---+---+
|   |   |--- b     |   |   |--- d
+---+---+          +---+---+
  |                  |
  a                  c

(cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd))
+---+---+    +---+---+
|   |   |--- |   |   |--- d
+---+---+    +---+---+
  |            |
  |            c
+---+---+
|   |   |--- b
+---+---+
  |
  a
```

To get `((a . b) (c . d))` you have to:

```
(cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons (cons 'c 'd) '()))
==> ((a . b) (c . d))

+---+---+        +---+---+
|   |   |------- |   |   |--- NIL/()
+---+---+        +---+---+
  |                |
  |                |
+---+---+        +---+---+
|   |   |--- b   |   |   |--- d
+---+---+        +---+---+
  |                |
  a                c
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, I decided to put the other answer as the correct one since it was the actual reasons why lisp/scheme printing behavior is not acting as I expected. Still, your answer also cleared a lot of things.